# quartz API - learn about executed jobs

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to get information about already executed (finished) jobs? I browsed the javadocs, learned how to fetch JobDetails etc. but can't find way to learn about the jobs that has already been executed (and finished).

any hints?

Comment: hm, trigger.getPreviousFireTime() I suppose

Answer (score 1):

You can get next trigger time using below code and compare it with cuurent time, if execution time is in past then job has already executed:

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

   for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {

     for (JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {

      String jobName = jobKey.getName();
      String jobGroup = jobKey.getGroup();

      //get job's trigger
      List<Trigger> triggers = (List<Trigger>) scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
      Date nextFireTime = triggers.get(0).getNextFireTime(); 
      Date currTime = new Date();

      if(currTime>nextFireTime )     
        System.out.println("[jobName] : " + jobName + " [groupName] : "
            + jobGroup + " - " + has already executed);

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of detailed history of all executions for jobs, then you simply have to make an implementation to keep track of all this information. You can use listeners to for this purpose.

Depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, you may either use  [JobListeners](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/JobListeners) ,[TriggerListeners](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/TriggerListeners) or [SchedulerListeners](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/SchedulerListeners).

For 'global' JobListeners:

```
<initialize JobListeners>
public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {

        try
        {
            jobKey = context.getJobDetail().getKey();

            schedulerName = context.getScheduler().getSchedulerName();
            jobName = jobKey.getName();
            groupName = jobKey.getGroup();
            
            //execution
            Date startDate = context.getFireTime();
            
            //execution time
            long runTime=context.getJobRunTime();

            //execution end
            long endDateM = startDate.getTime() + runTime;
            Date endDate = new Date(endDateM);

            //get more information here
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Note: Please be vary of the performance impact listeners can cause. As mentioned in the Quartz Docs:

> One thing that CAN slow down quartz itself is using a lot of listeners
> (TriggerListeners, JobListeners, and SchedulerListeners). The time
> spent in each listener obviously adds into the time spent "processing"
> a job's execution, outside of actual execution of the job.
>
> This
> doesn't mean that you should be terrified of using listeners, it just
> means that you should use them judiciously - don't create a bunch of
> "global" listeners if you can really make more specialized ones. Also
> don't do "expensive" things in the listeners, unless you really need
> to. Also be mindful that many plug-ins (such as the "history" plugin)
> are actually listeners.